# Show HTML inside VLC

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I am writing a vlc extension.
It should add a search box in vlc , where a user can google/youtube search anything and the search results(html page) are to be displayed inside the vlc window.
I can add the search box extension using lua script but I dont have any idea on how to display html page inside vlc.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display html content within VLC because it does not include a HTML renderer. You can display formatted text though.

Adding a html renderer would double VLC download and installation size and would only be beneficial to very small group of users, so we actively decided against this move.